# how to start spark applications without a 30second startup penalty?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

when doing a spark-submit it takes 30seconds to do anything, i believe it is binding to a port on sparkmaster, creating sparkcontext, allocating executors, jvm startup.etc

Anyway to speed this up? I will be calling the jar with different arguments every 3mins and want to reduce the latency

I've tried reading the jar with local:/ which seems to save a few seconds

Answer (score 1):

I know that spark has a default delay when you consistently request more resources than your cluster has available. This is controlled by the setting: `spark.scheduler.maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime`, found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), and defaults to 30s.

> Maximum amount of time to wait for resources to register before
>   scheduling begins.

Basically, the spark scheduler waits this long or until the number of requested executors are registered with your driver. If you always request more executors than what are available in your cluster, you'll always get this delay.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can speed this up a lot. First thing, there are lots of tasks that YARN and application master have to do before they can start your application.

YARN has to check the resources and decide where to spin up the new application. Allocate application master, Application master then communicates with Resource Manager to find out resources available and get the best resources possible for given input data.

Then start worker threads on executor nodes, start JVM threads, etc. Also, some delay is possible because of unavailability of resources. So, I doubt you can be sure that it will start in 30 seconds every time.

Also, I don't know why this delay can cause problem during start up.

Batch processing is usually delayed because of they being batch process. Spark streaming is also delayed because it doesn't start spark process until they have accumulated enough data from streaming sources and it will catch up if there are enough resources.
If you need realtime streaming then probably Flink would be better option until spark comes up with real time processing solution.

Comment: i'm not using YARN, using spark standalone scheduler